# How can I read new content as it gets loaded with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, mutation-observers

I am writing a Chrome/Firefox extension that collects data from new Twitter posts as they are loaded into the feed.

I tried using `MutationObserver`s and here is my current code:

```js
function checkForNewPosts(targetNode) {
    const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutationsList) {
        for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
            for (let node of mutation.addedNodes) {
                node.style.outline = '2px solid red !important' // for debug
            }
        }
    })

    observer.observe(targetNode, {childList: true})
}


let observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations, observer) {
    let targetNode = /* Just a really long query selector */ document.querySelector("#react-root > div > div > div.css-1dbjc4n.r-18u37iz.r-13qz1uu.r-417010 > main > div > div > div > div > div > div.css-1dbjc4n.r-1jgb5lz.r-1ye8kvj.r-13qz1uu > div > section > div > div > div > div") 
    if (targetNode) {
        observer.disconnect()
        checkForNewPosts(targetNode)
    }
})

observer.observe(document, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
})
```

This code works as intended until checkForNewPosts and then the observer can't find any mutations.

Comment: Either remove observer.disconnect() or call observe() again after checkForNewPosts.

Comment: I strongly recommend against using a MutationObserver that's so all encompassing as your `document` MutationObserver and that does a DOM walk with every change to the DOM. That's likely to be a performance nightmare. While it will be more complex, you're likely better off with something that is much more focused at finding the exact thing you're looking for, even if that means you need to create multiple MutationObservers as you descend the DOM tree.

Comment: An alternative, which would still be a notable performance hit, but which should be much better, would be to debounce the call to the code that runs the check in the DOM for the element (e.g., put it in a function separate from the observer, and use `setTimeout`) such that you're only actually checking for the presence of the thing you're looking for after there's something like 20 to 100ms between calls to the observer function.

Comment: As to you your actual question, there's not enough information here to answer this question, other than in generalities. To determine when things are changed in the DOM, the right way is a MutationObserver, as you've already determined. The one you're using may or may not be effective. We can't know without access to the HTML before and after the change (which would need to be in the question). The other main alternative is to snoop on the in-page JavaScript receiving the data that eventually is placed in the DOM. That's almost certainly received via either AJAX calls and/or a WebSocket.